# Why $z^2$ doubles the angle?

Tags: complex-analysis

$z^2$ is not a conformal map at zero because it doubles the angles. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Take two complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ and write them in polar form.

$z_1 = |z_1|(\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)$ and $z_2 = |z_2|(\cos\phi + i\sin \phi)$

Multiply them togehter.

$z_1z_2 = |z_1z_2|(\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin \theta\sin \phi + i(\cos\theta\sin\phi + \sin\theta\cos\phi))$

Notice that these trig expressions fit the double angle formula.

$z_1z_2 = |z_1z_2|(\cos(\theta+\phi) + i\sin(\theta+\phi))$

Multiplying two complex numbers adds the angles.  And squaring a complex number doubles the angles.

Comment: If this were the entire answer, the conclusion would be that $z \mapsto z^2$ was nowhere conformal. However it is conformal on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Conformality is a question about the angles between curves, not just the arguments.